# How to add masks on the detected face in iOS?

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0

I am developing an iOS app which detects face and does face tracking. I have implemented this using Open CV. Now I need to add masks on the detected face without using core image. I have a fair knowledge about Opengl es and open cv. I searched a lot on internet and couldn't find much information regarding adding masks in detail.

Comment: Masks in the graphics sense or masks as in party masks?

Comment: Party masks like the ones used in MSQRD and Snapchat

Comment: Your question is both too broad and too vague for Stack Overflow. You need to provide a lot more background, and show what you've tried. In general, what you need to do is define the polygons that define the region you want to draw and then render your mask texture onto those pologons.

Comment: tq Duncan.Do you have any idea on creating a mesh on the detected face?